# Is it possible to tell TypeScript a particular function call in a Node module should use browser's types and not Node's?

Tags: typescript, playwright

In Playwright code inside `page.evaluate` runs in browser environment, while code outside it runs in Node. Since TypeScript doesn't understand this (unsurprisingly), it thinks `setTimeout` has type

```
declare function setTimeout(callback: (...args: any[]) => void, ms?: number, ...args: any[]): NodeJS.Timeout;
```

from `node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts`. But inside `page.evaluate` `setTimeout` returns a number. Is there a nice way to tell TS about it? For now I just cast the result

```
setTimeout(...) as unknown as number
```

but I would prefer to avoid type assertions if possible.